# TinyMCE changing HREF from “/category/product-name” to “../../../../category/product-name”

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I have been using TinyMCE for a while now and I have not experienced this problem before. Although every time I try to add a href link to the text it is adding the unwanted '../'. Maybe this is a common problem, but I don't know what you would call '../' or back a directory

```
convert_urls: false,
relative_urls: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to take a look at this post about configuring TinyMCE for whether to use relative links:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/url_conversion.php

It covers lots of different options